# What are things that can happen off-screen and things that can't happen off-screen in a film, comics, or other visual media?

Tags: creative-writing, script

What are things that can happen off-screen and things that can't happen off-screen in a film, comics, or other visual media?

Let's take an example:

> "Hey, Jim, why did you hit him in the face" (Jim hit Jeremy in the
> face off screen)
>
> "It's none of your business, get out of my way!"

I am not sure if this happens often, I think in a TV show like Friends, it does happen from time to time, but I am wondering if there are situations where this is really bad or even terrible. I am guessing if it's an important action or event in the story, it could be terrible, but at the same time I think some important actions sometimes happen off-screen. Now, I am wondering if there's some kind of rule or standards used to know if an event should or should not happen off-screen.

Comment: This seems like a very broad question. Can you focus it for us? We can't generate a list of all possible on/off-screen actions

Comment: Pretty much _anything_ can happen off-screen. The whole world can end or be transformed. (Though pulling it off well is another matter.) However, if you follow a certain character closely, what they experience should be on-screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are thinking about this the wrong way around. Try instead: what can happen onscreen? Unless your budget is mega, you can't, for example, have a plane crash in a soap opera.

I wrote a play where a character is murdered offstage because it would have been too dangerous to do it while the audience was watching.

Comics are slightly different because the economics are different. Consider, however, social norms, such as sexual assault and child abuse.

With all genres you have to work out what the audience is going to think and take away from the scene. There can't be rules for this (unless you want to say indecent acts can't be shown). You are the artist who decides what is necessary and what is not.